# Keyboard fails in IE8 after AJAX call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I've run into a strange problem with an HTML form.  I've built a dynamic table that adds a new row when you enter data into an existing blank row; because there are some server requirements in adding a row, I make an AJAX call to do this in the onblur event.  It took a while to make this work for all browsers, but eventually all was happy with the world ... until IE8.  Now, what happens is that, when the call returns from AJAX, the cursor shows in the next textbox (correctly), but the keyboard no longer works.  I have to close the modal window (actually an IFRAME), then the keyboard starts to work again.  If I put IE8 into compatibility mode, it works fine.

Has anybody seen behavior like this, or have any ideas for a workaround?

Thanks, Jim

Comment: Post your AJAX call and the callback function. Can't really teall what's happening without seeing the code.

Comment: There's a huge amount going on.  If nobody has any immediate ideas, I'll try to put something together.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with DIVs placed above an INPUT, that *cloacked* the cursor... and once the DIV was not above it, the cursor appeared back again.

Just an idea: Maybe your IFRAME captured the focus (and/or the keyboard).

Comment: Yes, this appears to have been the issue.  I set the focus somewhere else, then set it back, and everything was copasetic!